# What is the difference between Registry.LocalMachine and RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, registry

What is the difference between `Registry.LocalMachine` and `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default)`?

And if there is no difference at all, what would be the preferred solution to use? For backwards compatibility with older .NET frameworks only the first solution (`Registry.LocalMachine`) is available but which API will survive in the future?

Registry.LocalMachine solution on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine.aspx

RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey solution on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the default view (`Registry64` for a 64-bit app, `Registry32` for a 32-bit app), then I'd use the first.

Comment: Can I conclude from this answer that there isn't a difference between the two unless you want a specific (non-default) view?

Comment: Yes, Registry.LocalMachine will give you the default view.

Answer (score -1):

[msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393042(v=vs.85).aspx)

The RegistryValueChangeEvent class represents changes to a single value of a specific key. For more information about using the WMI registry event classes, see Modifying the System Registry. For code examples, see WMI Tasks: Registry.
The following syntax is simplified from Managed Object Format (MOF) code and includes all inherited properties. Properties and methods are in alphabetic order, not MOF order.
Syntax

Comment: But Windows XP does not support the WMlQuery

Comment: The original question is about the difference between the two listed APIs, not about the the most ideal API (although I don't see how this API would be more suitable than the one mentioned in the question).